# What is wrong with my simple code here?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am having problems writing this simple program. I am just starting out with Python and was hoping for some help. When I run the start() function at the bottom of the programme, everything works fine until after the first raw_input(). If the user types "get coffee" for example, the string "Fair enough take a break" is printed but after this, rather than running the coffee() function like I would like, it just loops through to the start() function again.

Would someone be able to help please?
Thanks a lot.

```
def engine(next_scene):
    scenes = {"start":start(),"coffee":coffee(),"work":work()}
    return scenes[next_scene]

def start():
    print "you are in the office"
    print "you wonder what to do"
    action = raw_input("what do you do? Get coffee or work?")

    if action == "get coffee":
        print "Fair enough take a break"
        next_scene = "coffee"
        engine(next_scene)
    if action == "work":
        print "Good man, you are well on your way to being a coder"
        next_scene = "work"
        engine(next_scene)

def coffee():
    print "You walk out of the room"
    print "You head down the stairs and into the cafe"
    print "You order an espresso"
    print "You neck it down"
    print "Yumm"
    print "You are wired"
    action = raw_input("Now what? Work or go home? > ")

    if action == "work":
        print "You head back upstairs"
        next_scene = "work"
        engine(next_scene)
    if action == "go home":
        print "You lazy git"

def work():
    print "You beaver away and become a cool coder"
    next_scene = "start"
    engine(next_scene)

start()
```

Comment: I think you want to remove the `()` after your functions in the scenes dictionary.  Including the parenthesis tries to call those functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
scenes = {"start":start(),"coffee":coffee(),"work":work()}
```

should be

```
scenes = {"start":start,"coffee":coffee,"work":work}
```

You called the functions in the dictionary definition, but you just want to get the function object.

Comment: And the OP probably wants to change the following line to: `return scenes[next_scene]()`

Comment: Yes, of course. And he has to take care that he doesn't stack the calls to `engine`.

Comment: @Mathias.Thanks for your help.Sorry but how do I go about actually calling the function coffee() then in the event next_scene = "coffee"? Sorry for the basic questions.

Comment: @Reno: Have a look at Jon Clements comment. Or do something like `func = engine(next_scene)` followed by `func()`.

Comment: @JonClements thank you, I understand how to call the function now.

Comment: @JonClements This code seems to run with the function call in the dictionary, any idea what the difference is?  Sorry for the formatting, I cant work out how to make a new line in comments.

`def engine(next_scene):`      
    `scenes = {"LBS":"ack LBS","coffee":coffee(),"work":"ack work"}`  
    `return scenes[next_scene]`  
  
`def office():`  
    `print "you are in the office"`  
    `next_scene = "coffee"`  
    `engine(next_scene)`  
  
`def coffee():`  
    `print "cool, coffee"`  
  
`office()`

Answer (score 1):

Your engine function should like.

```
def engine(next_scene):
    scenes = {"start":start,"coffee":coffee,"work":work}
    scenes[next_scene]()
```